# Can't check checkboxes on second attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't check checkboxes on second attempt(i can check then uncheck, but after this no effect)

See http://jsfiddle.net/SM5qU/1/

Attributes set to checked="checked" but no visual effect.
I am using MacOS and tested in Chrome and Firefox

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />

<button id="check">Check</button>
<button id="uncheck">Uncheck</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').attr('checked', true)
})

$('#uncheck').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').attr('checked', false)
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.prop()` in your case:

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);

$(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` on base properties:

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true)
})

$('#uncheck').click(function() {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false)
})
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/SM5qU/2/)